# Jetty custom console startup message

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

So I have an embedded jetty instance and when I start it up I get the following output printed to my console.

```
> 2017-08-04 14:10:11.719:INFO::main: Logging initialized @193ms to
> org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog 2017-08-04
> 14:10:12.134:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.6.v20170531 Aug 04, 2017
> 2:10:12 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
> INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.7 2014-03-12
> 18:11:31... 2017-08-04 14:10:12.944:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main:
> Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4149c063{/,null,AVAILABLE}
> 2017-08-04 14:10:12.958:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started
> ServerConnector@7de62196{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} 2017-08-04
> 14:10:12.958:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1434ms
```

My question is, how would I change this to a custom message printed to my console on startup. Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the Jetty logging before you initialize anything Jetty, then do what you want with it.

Consume it, filter it, replace it, show as is, etc ...

Call:

```java
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog(new MyLogImpl());
```